# What memory security settings are needed to allow a basic buffer overflow on Fedora 25?

Tags: linux, c, buffer-overflow

I'm having a rather difficult time determining what memory security settings need to be adjusted on a fresh install of Fedora 25 in order to perform basic buffer overflows in the C language. As a newbie, this has been the toughest to figure out. I have several books and have watched several tutorials but every single one either provides a CD of a specific Linux install, or a asks to set up a VM. Unfortunately, I've had a very tough time setting up a VM on Windows (many different errors, terrible performance, etc...) and my Linux box is old, probably far too old to have enough memory to VM.

That said, **are there any OS settings that would by default prevent a buffer overflow from happening on a fresh Fedora 25 install?** If so, which settings and how could I disable them? I've tried to perform an attack on my own program and the memory addresses are the same in gdb every time I run the program. Also, *I am able to cause a segmentation fault by overflowing the buffer properly (canaries are disabled in the file)*, however, when I try to execute a function by using nm [myfile] on the command line, and entering the address into the overflow, the function does not execute, instead, I get a seg fault at best. I am working with 64 bit programs here.

Comment: possible duplicate http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66802/disable-stack-protection-on-ubuntu-for-buffer-overflow-without-c-compiler-flags

Comment: @Nordwald would this be the same for Fedora?

Comment: as far as I can tell these instructions seem distribution independent. Please confirm if it works for you.

Comment: @Nordwald will do

Comment: So far, no dice... Will post conclusion when found.